# Scikit-learn make_scorer custom metric problem for multiclass clasification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scoring

I was doing a churn analysis using:

```
randomcv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=clf,param_distributions = params_grid,
                          cv=kfoldcv,n_iter=100, n_jobs=-1, scoring='roc_auc')
```

and everything was fine, but then, I tried it with a custom scoring function this way:

```
def gain_fn(y_true, y_prob):
    tp = np.where((y_prob >= 0.02) & (y_true==1), 40000, 0)
    fp = np.where((y_prob >= 0.02) & (y_true==0), -1000, 0)
    return np.sum([tp,fp])

scorer_fn = make_scorer(gain_fn, greater_is_better = True, needs_proba=True)

randomcv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=clf,param_distributions = params_grid,
                          cv=kfoldcv,n_iter=100, n_jobs=-1, scoring=scorer_fn)
```

but I need to make a calculation, inside of `gain_fn`, with `y_prob` of a specific class (it has 3 possible values). Any suggestions?

Comment: Which class's probability are you interested in?  Probably all of them: you should have in mind a 3x3 matrix of gains/costs, an entry for each selected class vs actual class.  And then you have to think about how to translate three probabilities to class selection (as in your first edit on the [SO version of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68957102/10495893), to accommodate for the imbalance).

Answer (score 1):

`make_scorer` has a parameter `needs_proba` which is False by default, and you need to set it to True, thus instead of class label (output of clf.predict(...)), RandomizedSearchCV will pass a probability (output of clf.predict_proba(...)) into your scoring function:

```
scorer_fn = make_scorer(gain_fn, greater_is_better = True, needs_proba=True)
```

Comment: Yea, it’s true. But the point is which probability? I have 3 class labels. I can have 0.2, 0.3 and 0.5 for each class. How to know?

Comment: Once you set it to `True` it will pass a matrix of size Nx3, where N is number of objects. Thus, it will pass all three probabilities - the output of `clf.predict_proba(X)`. So in your custom function `gain_fn` the parameter `y_prob` will be Nx3 matrix.